# Tengo una duda sobre el uso de pipe y and | & en python

Tags: python

Buenas encontré un ejercicio así:

```py
and 
>>> 5&7 
5

or
>>> 5|7
7
```

Más en ninguno de los casos puedo entender como funciona, alguien podria indicarme porfavor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En inglés se llaman operadores de bitwise:

El primero (**&**) es el bitwise **AND**:  Descompone los números en binario, y se hace la “suma” del siguiente modo:

1x1=1, 1x0=0, 0x1= 0, 0x0=0

010**1** (5) AND 
 001**1** (3)
———————
          000**1**(1)

En cambio, para el **or** (**|**), se hace la “suma” del siguiente modo:

El resultado es 0 si los dos números son 0, los demás son 1

0**101**OR
0**011**
————————
0**111**

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora lo entiendo esas operaciones son a nivel binario. Si pudiera te daria +1 :(

Comment: Puedes agradecerselo aceptando su pregunta. Pulsa el tick que está debajo de la puntuación.